# Why I am getting this assertion error in skfuzzy?

Tags: python, error-handling, assertion, fuzzy-logic

I have this code of my fuzzy logic controller:

```
temperatura_zew = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 41, 1), 'temperatura_zew')
czas_chlodzenia = ctrl.Consequent(np.arange(0, 16, 1), 'czas_chlodzenia')

czas_chlodzenia_ctrl = ctrl.ControlSystem(\[rule1, rule2, rule3\])
czas_chlodzenia_sim = ctrl.ControlSystemSimulation(czas_chlodzenia_ctrl)

temperatura_zew.input\['temperatura_zew'\] = 25

czas_chlodzenia_sim.compute()

print("Czas chłodzenia:", czas_chlodzenia_sim.output\['czas_chlodzenia'\])
```

While debugging the code I am getting this error:

```
line 28, in <module>
    temperatura_zew.input['temperatura_zew'] = 25
```

```
assert isinstance(key, ControlSystemSimulation)
```